# Difference in java generics

Tags: java, generics

please , I want to know the difference between writing

```
public class Something<T extends Comparable<T>> {// }
```

and

```
public class Something<T extends Comparable> {// }
```

and how would that affect the code

Comment: A simple experiment will show you: write both and see how the compare method signature differs.

Comment: @duffymo What compare method?

Comment: When you implement the Comparable interface you have to write a compareTo() implementation.  My apologies for not spelling it out for you.

Comment: @duffymo `Something` is not implementing anything.

Comment: Actually, there is no difference at all in the generated code, unless it somehow manages to affect the choice of an overloaded method.

Comment: The question is incorrect, because Comparable is an interface.  A class implements it; another interface extends it.  And there's a big difference in the generated code.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case the type parameter `T` must be comparable to itself whereas in the second case `T` can be comparable to anything. Generally, when a class `C` is made comparable it is declared to implement `Comparable<C>` anyway. Nevertheless, here's an example of when the first wouldn't work but the second would:

```
class C1<T extends Comparable<T>> {  // first case
}

class C2<T extends Comparable> {  // second case
}

class A {  // some super class
}

class B extends A implements Comparable<A> {  // comparable to super class
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now:

```
new C1<B>();  // error
new C2<B>();  // works
```

In general, you should never use the second approach; try to stay away from raw types whenever possible. Also note that an even better option for the second approach would be

```
public class Something<T extends Comparable<? super T>> { /*...*/ }
```

Using this with `C1` would allow the `new C1<B>()` line above to compile as well.

Comment: Liked `Comparable<? super T>` `super` with Comparable you put value of type `T` into the `compareTo` method. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the difference is.

If you don't use generics in the interface you have to cast.  The signature includes `Object`:

```
package generics;

/**
 * NonGenericComparable description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944582/difference-in-java-generics?noredirect=1#comment27975341_18944582
 * @since 9/22/13 10:55 AM
 */
public class NonGenericComparable implements Comparable {
    private final int x;

    public NonGenericComparable(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        NonGenericComparable other = (NonGenericComparable) o;
        if (this.x < other.x) return -1;
        else if (this.x > other.x) return +1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

If you do you use the generic, you get greater type safety.   Casting isn't necessary.

```
package generics;

/**
 * GenericComparable uses generics for Comparable
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944582/difference-in-java-generics?noredirect=1#comment27975341_18944582
 * @since 9/22/13 10:53 AM
 */
public class GenericComparable implements Comparable<GenericComparable> {
    private final int x;

    public GenericComparable(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(GenericComparable other) {
        if (this.x < other.x) return -1;
        else if (this.x > other.x) return +1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Casting isn't necessary simply because the compiler generates the cast.  The generated code is identical.